# What is the PhotoEditorPro greyed out in the Gallery

Tags: photos, gallery

I am using Android 8.1 in a Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime.
If I open a picture in the Gallery, and I hit the three-dot menu at the top right, there are 5 items in the menu.
The last item is *Open in Photo Editor Pro*, and it is always greyed out.

[image].

**Which is that app? (link to Google Play)**

**If I install it, would that menu item become available?**

This is what I see when looking for Photo Editor Pro

[image]

Comment: Google search results indicate that Samsung used to offer this "Photo Editor Pro" feature for image editing, but one or the other Android update removed this functionality. https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&hl=en&pws=0&filter=0&q=%22photo+editor+pro%22+%22gallery%22+%22samsung%22+%22oreo%22

Comment: @Firelord - Thanks. Will check the links. From a quick look, I understand the Photo Editor Pro was gone when updating from Oreo to Pie, which is not my case.
I will post more detail.